# MySQL IN operator of result from another column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

`users(uid, name, titles)
titles(uid, name)`

users:

`uid | name | titles
1     David   2,4
2     John    5
3     Jane    4`

titles:

`uid | name
2     Owner
4     CEO
5     Manager`

The question is how do I select something like this:

`SELECT u.* FROM users as u
    JOIN titles as t
        ON t.uid IN (u.titles)
    WHERE t.uid=2`

Notice the `IN(u.titles)`? It's only taking the first title uid in u.titles field. That means when I change condition to `WHERE t.uid=4`, it shows no records.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users as u
JOIN titles as t ON find_in_set(t.uid, u.titles) > 0
WHERE t.uid=2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that each user can have multiple titles I would recommend a reference table which references the users to the titles.